# CSS media queries no funcionan

Tags: html, css, mediaqueries

Tengo un problema al usar `@media`. A mi criterio, no encuentro ningún error de sintaxis y no funciona.

```css
* {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.nav__responsive-ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  background-color: slateblue;
}

.nav-li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-li:hover>a {
  color: #ccc;
}

.nav-li:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.nav-li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-li i {
  width: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

@media only screen and(max-width: 500px) {
  .nav__ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/23c59c2ff6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__ul">
      <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><a href="#">Gana dinero</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><a href="#">ayuda</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav__responsive-ul">
      <div class="nav__responsive-button"></div>
      <div class="nav__li-container">
        <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
        <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><a href="#">Gana dinero</a></li>
        <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><a href="#">ayuda</a></li>
      </div>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

El error comienza cuando reduzco el width de la pantalla a menos de `500px`, según el código al hacer esto el `.nav__ul` tendría que desaparecer pero no lo hace.

Me gustaria entender el error y hallar la solución.

Comment: Podrías quitarle el ```only screen and``` y eso solucionaría el problema Te dejo este link como referencia de como usar media query: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que te faltaba es poner un espacio en la declaración de la media query, después de `and` y antes de los paréntesis, aquí puedes verlo arreglado. (Te puse un comentario para que lo veas bien, pero el comentario no cuenta para nada, ya que es ignorado por el intérprete

```css
* {
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    
    
    
    .nav__responsive-ul {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav{
        background-color: slateblue;
    }
    
    .nav-li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 9px;
        color: #ffffff;
    
    }
    
    .nav-li:hover > a{
        color: #ccc;
    
    }
    
    .nav-li:hover{
        color: #ccc;
    
    }
    
    .nav-li a{
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .nav-li i {
        width: 30px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and /*<- Ahora hay un espacio ahí ves?*/(max-width: 500px){
        .nav__ul {
            display: none;
        }
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/23c59c2ff6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__ul">
            <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><a href="#">Gana dinero</a></li>
            <li class="nav-li"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><a href="#">ayuda</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav__responsive-ul">
        <div class="nav__responsive-button"></div>
        <div class="nav__li-container">
            <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><a href="#">Gana dinero</a></li>
            <li class="nav_responsive-li"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i><a href="#">ayuda</a></li>
        </div>
            
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Por cierto, te recomiendo que no utilices dos clases diferentes para hacer las cosas responsivas... eso está haciendo que dupliques el código, en vez de eso utiliza solo una clase y en la media-query redefine cómo quieres que se vea esa clase cuando la query está activa!!

Answer (score -2):

and es un operador no una función de CSS 3, and, debe de usarse para lógica de la siguiente manera and () no and(), tienes que colocar un espacio entre estos para evitar ambigüedades

Comment: podrias ver [answer], y hacer tu respuesta un poco mas clara? gracias...